# Need Reference to Object For Class CTOR (before Object is built)

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

See the the ? mark for the question.

```
public class Person 
{
    public Int16 ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<Toy> Toys { get; private set; }
    public Person(Int16 id, string name, List<Toy> toys)
    { ID = id; Name = name; Toys = toys; } 
}
public class Toy
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Person Owner { get; private set; }
    public Toy(Person owner, string name)  
    { Owner = owner; Name = name; }
}
```

The problem is with the Person CTOR.  How to pass toys to the Person ctor?  Toy needs Owner in the Toy ctor but that Owner has not yet been built yet.

I understand I can move Toys out of the Person CTOR and make the set public.  Assume you only get the toys you are born with - the private set; has a purpose.  And I understand that what I am asking for may not be possible.

Like anyone really cares but Toy only needs to know it Owners name so I may just modified Toys.

```
  public class Toy
  {
     private Person owner;
     private string ownerName;

     public string Name { get; private set; }
     public String OwnerName 
     { 
        get
        {
           if (!string.IsnullOrEmpty(ownerName)) return ownerName;
           elseif (owner != null) return owner.Name;
           else throw new exception("homelesstoy");
     }
     public Toy( string name, Person owner)  
     { 
         Name = name; Owner = owner;
         // new toy need to write it to DB 
     }
     public Toy( string name, string _ownerName)  
     { 
         Name = name; ownerName = _ownerName;
     }
  }
```

In a whacked kind of way this is better.  If my toy is is my car and they have my keys I don't want them to know my address.  From my name the police can find me if the car is recovered.

Comment: It is possible though not safe, if these both classes (Person and Toy) are members of another (container) class, let's say Family. It is possible to initialize references in container's constructor initializer list.

Comment: Does the `Toy` need to know it's owner?  If the `Toy` is within the `Person` class, then by that logic you already know that the `Toy` is owned by that person.

Comment: Psst... The first assignment in the `Person` constructor is the wrong way around... fix it quick, and I’ll promise not to tell anyone ;-)

Comment: @Matthew There is a difference between does an owner know what toys he has and does the toy know its owner.  And yes the toy need to know its owner.

Comment: @Blam I understand the difference, however if the `Toy`s are always accessed from using the `Person` object, then you already know its parent.

Comment: @Flot2011 Toy is really an AuditTrail that is associated with both a Document and Author and AuditTrail (Toy) needs to stand on it's own.  The AuditTrail that get loaded to the Author is just a static list of the last 400 when the program starts for the purpose of hey I did not make those changes or the changes I made yesterday are not there and to remind the user their actions are recorded.

Comment: @Matthew What if I find a toy in the yard and want to know who its owner is.  I don't want to go to every owner and ask them if this is their toy.  And I may trust the toy more than the owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the setter on `Owner` private? I can understand your point about the setter on `Toys` in the `Person` class.

If you removed that constraint, you could create a backing store (full property) and then loop the toys list in the `Person` constructor and do `item.Owner = this`.

```
public class Toy
{
    private Person _owner = null;
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Person Owner { 
         get { return _owner; }; 
         set {
              if(_owner != null) throw new InvalidOperationException("No Stealing");
              _owner = value;
         }
    }
    public Toy(Person owner, string name)  
    { Owner = owner; Name = name; }
}
```

This would allow you to set `Owner` only once and subsequent calls to the setter would be exceptional.  You wouldn't need to change the constructor, because you could still do:

```
Toy batman = new Toy(null, "Bruce");
```

One problem that I see is that this Toy-Owner relationship doesn't model the real world.  Children *are* sometimes born with a slew of toys at their disposal, but toys are hardly ever manufactured with an immediate owner. Even after a toy is created and given to someone, it can be given to someone else.

I think the conceptual details are tripping you up logically.

edit:
forgot the constructor...

```
public Person(Int16 id, string name, List<Toy> toys)
{ 
    id = ID; 
    Name = name; 

    foreach(Toy item in toys) {
        item.Owner = this;
    }

    Toys = toys; 
}
```

Comment: Public set; on Toy Owner is OK.   Cool solution.

Comment: `internal` is preferable. And the exception should be an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: @Blam: This is not a very good solution because now you have to trust your client code never to change the `Owner` of a toy without also removing the toy from its owner’s list of toys. You should at least make the setter *internal* instead of *public*.

Comment: And yes, the exception should be `InvalidOperationException`, it should have a meaningful exception message, and all the code should also check for `null` values and throw `ArgumentNullException` accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote.  Maybe I should mention that most people don't agree with the single-set property as shown. I don't feel strongly one way or the other about it. It can be argued that properties should never throw exceptions and, yes, you should throw a more specific exception.  I'd personally have a method on `Toy` called `SetOwner(Person person)` which handles the behavior that I've posted.

Comment: @Timwi It wasn't my intention to post a production-ready solution, but an example of how this could be done logically.  I agree with what you've said, but this isn't a 'write my code for me' community.

Comment: In this case Toy is really an AuditTrail of the person actions and as such is not transferable and is not valid without a Person.  Creating the AuditTrailItem with actions and without an Author (Person) violates that constraint but I can live with live with that.   Where I get into this situation is when the program starts and loads history from the DB.

Comment: I missed and hit a downvote when I was trying to check.  Could you change you answer so I can remove the down vote?

Comment: Funny. I missed an hit delete instead of edit when I noticed I missed the `new` operator.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I hear you. What I am going to do is throw an exception if toys in Person ctor has an owner.  If I enforce Toy must have an Owner in the Toy ctor then I also take a chance I pass a toys to the Person they don't own.  A class can only do so much to protect itself and at some point the program logic needs to protect the classes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities I can think of:

- If you want to keep the classes the way you have them now, you can create a Person with an empty list of Toys and add the toys afterwards, e.g.:

  ```
  var newPerson = new Person(id, name, new List<Toy>());
  var newToy = new Toy(newPerson, toyName);
  newPerson.Toys.Add(newToy);
  ```
- If you want the list to be immutable after creation, then you should declare it as a `ReadOnlyCollection<Toy>` instead. In this situation, I recommend to have a static method that creates the whole lot in one operation:

  ```
  public class Person 
  {
      public Int16 ID { get; private set; }
      public string Name { get; private set; }
      public ReadOnlyCollection<Toy> Toys { get; private set; }
      public Person(Int16 id, string name, List<Toy> toys)
      { ID = id; Name = name; Toys = toys; } 

      public static Person CreateWithToys(Int16 id, string name,
          IEnumerable<string> toyNames) // or could use “params string[]”, too
      {
          var person = new Person(id, name, null);
          var toys = new ReadOnlyCollection<Toy>(
              toyNames.Select(toyName => new Toy(person, toyName)).ToList());
          person.Toys = toys;
      }
  }

  [...]

  var jimmy = Person.CreateWithToys(47, "Jimmy",
      new[] { "Rattle", "Batman costume", "Nuclear missile" });

  // or, if you used “params string[]” above,
  var jimmy = Person.CreateWithToys(47, "Jimmy",
      "Rattle", "Batman costume", "Nuclear missile");
  ```

  In more complex cases, you may have to make some of the setters *internal* instead of *private* so that such a static method can access what it needs to access.

Comment: How can I access the Toys directly?  I find some Toys on the lawn and need to find their owner.  Could the CreateWithToys pass Toys back out?

Comment: @Blam: I’m sorry, I don’t understand your question. The first example already shows how you can access `newPerson.Toys`. In the second example you can just access `jimmy.Toys`. What exactly is unclear about the way this works?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a Person instance to the Toy constructor, and have the new Toy add itself to the Person's Toys collection, instead of passing the Toys collection to the Person constructor.

Comment: This would also require changing the Person CTOR and removing the `List<Toy>` parameter since you can't create a `Toy` without an owner reference. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new Toy constructor and changing the Person setter of Toy to public;

```
public class Toy
{
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
    public Toy(string toyName);
}

public class Person
{
    Int16 id;
    string name;
    List<Toy> toys;
    public Person(Int16 id, string name, List<Toy> toys)
    { 
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.toys = new List<Toy>();
        this.AddToys(toys);

    }

    private void AddToys(List<Toy> toys)
    {
        foreach (var toy in toys)
        {
            this.toys.Add(toy);
            toy.Owner = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you actually answered this first but I read the answer from Jim first.  +1 and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know the `Toy` owner if you haven't created the owner yet. You need to make `Owner` a public setter and change the Toy CTOR.

Comment: I get making Toys a public set in Person and removing it from the CTOR but I am not following changing Toy CTOR.  I am not criticizing.  I am confused and may be missing something.

Comment: Remove `Person owner` as a parameter in the `Toy` CTOR. This will have to be assigned after you have a `Person` reference.